# Window batch script to truncate leading zeros in a text file and write to a new file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, batch-updates

Kindly help with a windows batch script that will remove the leading zeroes in a text file and write to a new file without the zeroes.

**Input file format**

```
0265952076
0263097520
0578361217
0266127789
0505834686
0578361190
```

**Output format**

```
265952076
263097520
578361217
266127789
505834686
578361190
```

Thank you.

Comment: i tried with script but am only able to write the last on the file onto the new file.                                               @ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::Extract only the first 5 characters


FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (%1) DO (
    SET "var1=%%a"

)

ECHO %var1:~1,9%>max_test.txt

Comment: put the last `)` to the very end (after max_test.txt) to include the echo into the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
(for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%a in (inputFile) do echo(%%a)>outputFile
```

This uses the hability of `for /f` to split a string in tokens, removing the delimiters used for the splitting. As the `0` is used as delimiter, but we are asking for all the string in only one token, `for` will discard initial delimiters until the first token is found, resulting in leading zeroes removed.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
type file.txt | repl "^0*" "" >newfile.txt 
pause
```